# logging DDE conversations in windows 10

Tags: logging, dde

I need to trace where a DDE conversation is failing in windows 10. This is handing a file path to

I always used DDESpy, but it crashes under win10 when monitoring events. I have tried running under all legacy modes.

Can the event viewer be configured to log DDE commands?

Comment: I'm interested in this, too. I haven't found an alternative to ddespy yet. Clearly, the event viewer cannot log DDE commands, though.

Comment: I made no progress on this. I heard a rumour that one of the pay-to-use versions of VisualStudio had a DDE monitor. Could not confirm. If your app relies on dde to associate with a file extension, our decision was to abandon dde, and deal with the multiple processes issue by detecting any existing instance of our app, handing the new file path to it, and closing the newly-create instance.

Comment: I made no progress on this. I heard a rumour that one of the pay-to-use versions of VisualStudio had a DDE monitor. Could not confirm. we had an issue where dde failes on windows 10, because it does not wait long enough for later MFC-authored apps to load. If your app relies on dde to associate with a file extension, our decision was to abandon dde, and deal with the multiple processes issue by detecting any existing instance of our app, handing the new file path to it, and closing the newly-create instance.  ....

Comment: Spy++ has a checkbox for monitoring DDE events and does not crash like DDESpy, HOWEVER, on my Win10 system, no DDE events appear to be logged (and I know there are events!)

Answer (score 0):

I also had a need to trace/debug DDE traffic.
Same experience as reported by others: old Spy++ crashes.
However, I located a working Spy++ and Spy++ (64 bit) in my
installation of Visual Studio 2010 - on Windows 10 Pro
The Spy++ and Spy++ (64) have much more tracing capabilities.
But most important, they do not crash (so far).

Regards, Max

Screenshot from using Spy++ from Visual Studio 2010:

[image: Screenshot from using Spy++ from Visual Studio 2010]